# Why is my authentication login not working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Can someone explain to me why this authentication logic is not working? Ty

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final InitialAuthenticationFilter initialAuthenticationFilter;
    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                        .addFilterAt(initialAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);


        http.authorizeHttpRequests(authorization ->
                authorization
//                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/register").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class InitialAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(
            HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response,
            FilterChain filterChain
    ) throws ServletException, IOException {
        byte[] body = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(request.getInputStream());
        Map<String, Object> jsonRequest = new ObjectMapper().readValue(body, Map.class);

        String email = jsonRequest.get("email").toString();
        String password = jsonRequest.get("password").toString();

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(email, password);

        authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/login");
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authenticationProvider.authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String password = String.valueOf(authentication.getCredentials());

        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        if(passwordEncoder.matches(password, userDetails.getPassword())) {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            userDetails,
                            null,
                            userDetails.getAuthorities());

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

            return authenticationToken;

        } else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Authentication failed");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Everything that I came up with. I need this custom authentication filter because I wanna have 2 providers(1 for user/pass authentication and 1 for otp authentication).

After I tried debugging, it seems like my user is being authenticated in the end, but I still get a 403 on the /login route. Can someone explain me why?

Comment: On the login route you only allow POST.

Comment: I didn't post the controller, but it's just the /login route...and it is in post: @RequestMapping(value = "/login" , method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void log(@RequestBody User user) {}

Comment: Which version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: For starters your `InitialAuthenticationFilter` is breaking things. You are consuming the request meaning there is nothing left for others to read. You are reading the inputstream. I don't see why you need a custom authentication manager only a provider which works with your custom authentication. Looking at what your custom provider does I even doubt you need this one. Only your filter which checks if it needs to authenticate or not.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli 3.1.2...@M. Deinum if I don't inject the authManager and call the authenticate method to delegate which provider to use, my custom provider is not picked up. What I wanna have essentially is two authentications(User/pass and User/otp). So in the custom filter I wanna check the body of the request and choose which authentication to use, then use the manager to deleger it's own provider.

Comment: I do not understand why you even need this filter  "InitialAuthenticationFilter", just remove this and you will be fine

Comment: if this is your first time using spring security, why are you not reading the spring security documentation?